# Which of these is correct - "Running on circle" or "Running in circle"?

Tags: grammar

Which of these is correct -  "Running on circle" or "Running in circle"? All I want to express is that we are doing same work again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[run around in circles](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+around+in+circles)***

> **go around/round in circles**  *also* **run around/round in circles**
>   to use a lot of time and effort trying to do something, without making any progress.

If you want to be specific about doing things again and again with no good outcome, choose **go around/round in circles** [on the same page of that link].

> **go around/round in circles** - *if you go round in circles when you are discussing something or trying to achieve something, you do not make any progress **because you keep going back** to the same subjects or the same problems.*

Answer (score 0):

**Running in circles** is a phrase that means you are doing an activity several times without making any progress. The plural circle**s** is essential.

Comment: In Britain I think we would be more inclined to say 'running round in circles'.

Comment: Running in circles is probably just the compressed version of running around in circles.

Comment: it suggests *aimless* activity not *repeated!*

Answer (score 0):

I think that neither phrase would be used by a native English speaker. **"Running around in circles"**, **"Going around in circles"**, **"Running in a circle"** or **"Retreading the same ground"** would be valid versions.

You may want to consider **"Reinventing the wheel"** which implies that the work is re-doing something that has already been done.

Comment: Also "running in a circle".

Comment: @GEdgar I've edited my answer to include that version too, thanks